# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS freezes after login

Tags: login

I have a desktop that I want to use for hosting servers. The desktop is running Windows XP so I decided to install Linux instead of using the unsupported XP.

So the first thing I did was to grab my laptop and plugged in a USB into it. Then I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit from ubuntu.com. Then I downloaded the Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux.com. I launched the software and followed the instructions. The program installed the things to my USB and then I turned of my laptop and plugged in the USB to my desktop.

I turned on the desktop and pressed F10 while starting up. 
The Boot Menu showed up and I could choose from where I wanted to boot. I choosed my USB. Then I could choose if I wanted to Try Ubuntu or Install and other things. I pressed Install Ubuntu. The Installation begun and everything where fine. I choose to install Ubuntu while keeping Windows XP (if the installation didn't work).

When the installation finished and the login screen was showing I wrote my password that was configured in the installation. Now only the background was showing and I was not able to move the cursor.

I have searched the internet but havent found anhthing that worked for me. I have tried opening the terminal using Alt + Shift + F2. But the terminal asked for my login so I entered my username (the name over the password-field on the login screen). Then I pressed Enter. The terminal asked for my password so I entered the password that I used on the login screen. No letters or stars was showing. I pressed Enter. It sakd Login Incorrect.

What should I do?? This is the first time I am using Linux. The desktop have almost 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: Note that login and password are both case-sensitive. If it saying login incorrect then probably you are mistyping your login name.

Comment: I have tried several times using the password that I enter on the login screen. On the login screen it works but not in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry for being stubborn but I still assume you're mistyping name.

Comment: Ok. I will check if I am misspelling.

Comment: I tried reinstalling and saw that my name and my username was different. I will try again.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to dual boot Ubuntu in 2gb RAM machine. Consider ligther flavours: Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Do you have an NVidia GPU???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by starting Ubuntu in safe mode and then changed my Additional Driver to a Nvidia Driver.